# Google Cloud Function returning "Error: could not handle the request"

Tags: python, python-requests, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to write simple python function and want to deploy it using GCF(Google Cloud Function).

```
def check_refresh_date(request):
    import requests
    requestData = requests.get(
        "https://coronavirus.data.gov.uk/downloads/json/coronavirus-cases_latest.json")
    return requestData
```

requirement.txt looks like:

```
certifi==2020.6.20
chardet==3.0.4
idna==2.10
numpy==1.19.0
pandas==1.0.5
python-dateutil==2.8.1
pytz==2020.1
requests==2.24.0
six==1.15.0
urllib3==1.25.9
wincertstore==0.2
```

When I trigger this function it returns

> "Error: could not handle the request"

on browser. In logs it is showing

> "Function execution took 490 ms, finished with status: 'crash'"

there is ongoing issue due to which it does not return exact error. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/155215191

I need help with

1. what is wrong with my function?
2. is there any workaround to get proper error message in logs or browser?
   This is just basic function, I need to extend this function after it works.

Comment: Are you using free tier? As far as I know, Firebase Cloud Functions don't allow you to use external API calls (which you do) if you're on the free tier.

Comment: @YaronGrushkaYes it is free tier. can you send me any link stating that.

Comment: How do you deploy and invoke your function?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiereinvoking function from browser and deploying using UI.

Comment: Have you tried using the workaround in the issue to get more detailed logs? (Putting the trigger function in a try-except and adding some sleep)

Comment: Do you have billing enabled? Cloud Functions cannot make external requests until billing is enabled.

Comment: @mgoya I am not able to. can you send sample code to do that?

Comment: @DustinIngramyes billing seems enabled as "enable billing" option is not coming up on billing page.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you are returning an HTTP response object, instead of the JSON response of your request.

You should do something like this:

```py
from flask import jsonify

def check_refresh_date(request):
    import requests
    res = requests.get(
        "https://coronavirus.data.gov.uk/downloads/json/coronavirus-cases_latest.json")
    data = res.json()
    return jsonify(data)
```